# RemoveProfile command not working in iOS MDM protocol

Tags: ios, configuration, profile, mdm

I'm trying to unenroll iOS devices that I enrolled using OTA enrollment described by Apple. But when I send a RemoveProfile command to a device targeting that MDM profile's identifier, I get an error saying "The profile “xxxxxxxxx” is not managed by MDM". This is necessary for me to achieve unenroll OTA. Please help. Thanks in advance... This is the configuration profile installed in my devices:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ConsentText</key>
    <dict>
        <key>default</key>
        <string>Espere mientras se instala el perfil</string>
    </dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadContent</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Challenge</key>
                <string>594EA2E1A5D1C883EF3BA2EA3B36A670</string>
                <key>Key Type</key>
                <string>RSA</string>
                <key>Key Usage</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>Keysize</key>
                <integer>2048</integer>
                <key>Name</key>
                <string>MDM-MYCANAME-CA</string>
                <key>Retries</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>RetryDelay</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>Subject</key>
                <array>
                    <array>
                        <array>
                            <string>O</string>
                            <string>MyCompany</string>
                        </array>
                    </array>
                    <array>
                        <array>
                            <string>CN</string>
                            <string>1</string>
                        </array>
                    </array>
                </array>
                <key>URL</key>
            <string>https://myWindowsServerCA/certsrv/mscep/mscep.dll</string>
        </dict>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>Configures SCEP</string>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>SCEP (MDM-MYCOMPANY-CA)</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.mycompany.SCEP.scep1</string>
        <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
        <string>My Company Name</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>com.apple.security.scep</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>B4FAD671-FD52-48CD-B342-5EE557055CAC</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>AccessRights</key>
        <integer>8191</integer>
        <key>CheckInURL</key>
        <string>https://mycheckinurl.com/WS/Mobile/iOSEnrollmentHandler.ashx?ec=1000156</string>
        <key>CheckOutWhenRemoved</key>
        <true/>
        <key>IdentityCertificateUUID</key>
        <string>B4FAD671-FD52-48C‚eD-B342-5EE557055CAC</string>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>Configures MobileDeviceManagement.</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.mycompany.AMDM.mdm1</string>
        <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
        <string>My Company Name</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>com.apple.mdm</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>5274CA69-3F9F-4E3D-A601-761E304AA84F</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>ServerURL</key>
        <string>https://myserverurl/WS/Mobile/iOSCommandHandler.ashx?ec=1000156</string>
        <key>SignMessage</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Topic</key>
        <string>com.apple.mgmt.External.8be7fb6b-321e-4c77-ac24-2055c8519fe4</string>
        <key>UseDevelopmentAPNS</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>PayloadDescription</key>
<string>Perfil MDM para control de dispositivos</string>
<key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
<string>MYCOMPANYMDM</string>
<key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
<string>com.mycompany.AMDM</string>
<key>PayloadOrganization</key>
<string>My company name</string>
<key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
<false/>
<key>PayloadType</key>
<string>Configuration</string>
<key>PayloadUUID</key>
<string>30232328-7BF6-4A37-9642-D07F50BFF28F</string>
<key>PayloadVersion</key>
<integer>1</integer>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is correct behavior. You initial profile isn't installed through MDM. It's installed through OTA.

If you want to unenroll a device, you should return error 401 (Unauthorized) when the device will checkin to the server to get next command.

Comment: I am getting "401 (Unauthorized)" at the time of installing the device.Can you please tell what is the reason for it?

Comment: Can you give more information? What does "time of installing the device" mean? Also, do you use your own server or some 3rd party MDM?

Comment: Right Now I am using OSX server for testing purpose in the same wifi.when I open the url to install the certificate it is showing verified but when I enroll the device I am getting two kinds of error.Some times it shows "401 (Unauthorized)" and some times 500 internal server error and also 405 method not supported.Is those issues related to the certification or some files are missing since earlier it was working fine for me.

Comment: Frankly, I am not sure what's going on. It could be just a bug in Profile Manager (based on the error 500 internal server).

Comment: Finally I was able to install Maverics server and install the devices.The issue was actually I has removed the server and installed again then the issue came.I tried in a different system in which server was not installed from before and it worked fine.Still I am unable to do it in the same system where I have removed the and reinstalled the server app.Can you please suggest me what can be the issue?

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea. May be it leaves something behind (like a DB) and it got into some corrupted state. I looked at Profile Manager only briefly, so don't have enough knowledge to figure about it.